# Make error - Installing package (regviewer) Error 1

Tags: compilation, installation, makefile, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install the "regiviewer" application.

As far as Im aware I have installed all the required dependencies.

As I go to ./configure the package, it completes this, returning no error and prompts me to 'make' (compile the package).

Upon doing so I get the following errors outputted:

```
make[2]: *** [ntreg.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/regviewer-0.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/regviewer-0.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I do not know what this means or how to rectify this. (fairly new to Linux)

Any help would be much appreciated :)

The full output is shown below:

```
/usr/local/src/regviewer-0.1$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/regviewer-0.1'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/regviewer-0.1/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. 
-DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\"   
-DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" 
-pthread -DORBIT2=1 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr   /include/libgnomeui-2.0 
-I/usr/include  /libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 
-I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 -I/usr /include/libgnome-2.0               
-I/usr/include /libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 
-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 
-I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 
-I/usr/include/libxml2 
-I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 
-I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include 
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/pixman-1 
-I/usr/include/libpng12      -g -O2 -MT ntreg.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ntreg.Tpo -c 
-o ntreg.o ntreg.c
ntreg.c: In function ‘parse_nk’:
ntreg.c:378:29: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:379:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:380:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:381:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:382:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:383:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:384:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:385:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:386:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:387:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:388:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:389:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:391:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c: In function ‘parse_vk’:
ntreg.c:410:31: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:412:31: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:413:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:415:18: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:417:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:418:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:420:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c: In function ‘parse_sk’:
ntreg.c:438:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:439:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:440:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:442:46: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:444:46: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c: In function ‘parse_lf’:
ntreg.c:462:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’,
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:471:12: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’,
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c: In function ‘parse_lh’:
ntreg.c:490:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’,
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:496:12: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’,
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c: In function ‘parse_li’:
ntreg.c:517:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c:522:5: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c: In function ‘nk_ls’:
ntreg.c:1326:7: warning: field width specifier ‘*’ expects argument of type ‘int’,
but argument 2 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat]
ntreg.c: In function ‘put_dword’:
ntreg.c:1999:17: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
ntreg.c: In function ‘fmyinput’:
ntreg.c:69:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with 
attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
make[2]: *** [ntreg.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/regviewer-0.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/regviewer-0.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The ntreg.c file: lines 1989 - 2000

```
/* And, yer basic DWORD write */

int put_dword(struct hive *hdesc, int vofs, char *path, int dword)
{
  struct keyval *kr;
  int r;

  ALLOC(kr,1,sizeof(int)+sizeof(int));

  kr->len = sizeof(int);
  (int)kr->data = dword;

  r = put_buf2val(hdesc, kr, vofs, path, REG_DWORD);

  FREE(kr);

  return(r);
}


/* ================================================================ */
```

Comment: The actual error is above the lines you have just given us. You need to include more output.

Comment: apologies, I have now amended

Comment: The actual error appears to be `ntreg.c:1999:17: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment` though in that sea of warnings it is hard to pick out. Include a handful of lines of the code from around that line please.

Comment: excuse me being technologically inept, but how do I do this?

Comment: Open the ntreg.c text file in a text editor of some sort. Find line 1999 and then copy and paste a generous handful of lines from around that point. (Sorry, the fact that 1999 is the line number in that error is not obvious unless you've dealt with it before.) Alternatively `sed -n 1989,2009p src/ntreg.c` should get what we need I believe.

Comment: Thank you, ive posted the lines 1989-2010 above !

Comment: That is an old project. I would slightly surprised if the code still worked. That being said it looks like things have changed in the source since that release (that line included). I would suggest that perhaps you might have more luck with the code from CVS (from 2009) than with that release from 2003).

Answer (score 0):

The error on the line in question appears to have been corrected in the upstream source between the date in 2003 that the 0.1 release was cut and the date in 2009 that the latest change was made in the CVS repo. I have no idea if the CVS code will ultimately work better or if the project, once compiled, will work at all correctly but that updated code base is likely a better place to start trying to work from.